# Допоможіть розставити розділові знаки в такому реченні

Tags: пунктуація

> Хлопці зустріли мене як і можна було очікувати: весело, жваво і з
>   новими трофеями: консервами і яблуками.

Виходить дві двокрапки в реченні?

Comment: Будь ласка, уточніть, що са́ме вам не подобається у цьому реченні, і чому. Щоб іншим користувачам не доводилося вгадувати.

Comment: @bytebuster Мені здається, що дві двокрапки це негарно.

Comment: Я не впевнена, але не бачу підстав для першої двокрапки. Як на мене, то *як і можна було очікувати* - не узагальнююче словосполучення/речення, бо можна видалити без особливої втрати сенсу. Я б розглядала як вставне речення, яке можна виділити комами або дужками. Мій варіант такий. *"Хлопці зустріли мене, як і можна було очікувати, весело, жваво і з новими трофеями: консервами і яблуками"* або *"Хлопці зустріли мене (як і можна було очікувати) весело, жваво і з новими трофеями: консервами і яблуками"*.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko  Мабуть ви праві, я прийняв би це як відповідь.

Comment: @БорисвітНежурбіда, у цьому-то і проблема. «Гарно/негарно» — це субʼєктивний критерій. Одному здається гарно, іншому — негарно.

Comment: @БорисвітНежурбіда, відповідь ще треба підготувати, підсилити аргументами, правилами. Може, згодом. Або будуть інші версії у колег. А Ви тим часом можете удосконалити формулювання свого запитання.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Дві можливі інтонації

Таке речення:

> Хлопці зустріли мене <1> як і можна було очікувати <2> весело, жваво і з новими трофеями.

— можна інтонувати двома способами:

1. Вважаючи основною частиною «хлопці зустріли мене весело, жваво і з новими трофеями». «Як і можна було очікувати» в такому випадку є вставною частиною ([per Oksana Gubrenko](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/1364#comment3702_1364)):

   > Хлопці зустріли мене (як і можна було очікувати) весело, жваво і з новими трофеями. *([§ 123, п. 2](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil5.htm#par123p2))*
   >   Хлопці зустріли мене, як і можна було очікувати, весело, жваво і з новими трофеями. *([§ 118, А, п. 11](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil5.htm#par118Ap11))*
   >   Хлопці зустріли мене — як і можна було очікувати — весело, жваво і з новими трофеями. *([§ 121, п. 14](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil5.htm#par121p14))*

   Проблеми двох двокрапок в такому випадку взагалі немає.
2. Вважаючи основною частиною «хлопці зустріли мене [так], як і можна було очікувати». «Весело, жваво і з новими трофеями» в такому випадку є поясненням до (суттєвої, а не вставної) частини «як і можна було очікувати».

   Перед переліком «весело, жваво і з новими трофеями» ставиться двокрапка за [§ 120, п. 1](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil5.htm#par120p1) — узагальнюючою частиною в такому випадку можна вважати «[так], як і можна було очікувати» (насправді відповідно до [примітки 1](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil5.htm#par120p1prym1) двокрапку можна ставити і без узагальнюючої частини). Також, якщо дуже хочеться, можна вважати «весело, жваво і з новими трофеями» окремим односкладним реченням, що розкриває зміст попереднього, і поставити ту саму двокрапку вже за [§ 120, п. 2](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil5.htm#par120p2).

   > Хлопці зустріли мене [так], як і можна було очікувати: весело, жваво і з новими трофеями.

   Але в такому випадку виникає проблема двох двокрапок (див. нижче).

Слід зазначити, що вибір між інтонацією 1 і інтонацією 2 **не корелює** з наявністю продовження («консервами і яблуками») і проблемою двох двокрапок. Я маю на увазі, що варіант 1 не має використовуватися як шлях уникнути двох двокрапок — вибір між варіантом 1 і варіантом 2 залежить від задуму автора (які частини суттєвіші і як він інтонує речення). Проблема двох двокрапок має вирішуватися іншим способом.

#### Проблема двох двокрапок у випадку інтонації 2

> Хлопці зустріли мене, як і можна було очікувати: весело, жваво і з новими трофеями: консервами і яблуками.

Припустимо, потрібна саме інтонація 2 — то що ж робити з двома двокрапками? (Можна банально взяти «консервами і яблуками» в дужки — але припустімо, що це нас не влаштовує.)

По факту замість двокрапки іноді ставлять тире.

- Другу двокрапку на тире замінювати, на мою думку, не варто — бо в конструкції «…: а, б, в — …» люди очікують після тире узагальнююче слово (за [§ 121, п. 5](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil5.htm#par121p5)) чи продовження речення, що почалося до двокрапки, — а не інший перелік, узагальнюючим словом для якого є останній член першого переліку.
- Відповідно лишається лише замінити на тире першу двокрапку:

  > Хлопці зустріли мене, як і можна було очікувати — весело, жваво і з новими трофеями: консервами і яблуками.

Як тоді можна аргументувати тире в скороченному реченні:

> Хлопці зустріли мене, як і можна було очікувати — весело, жваво і з новими трофеями.

?

Чесно, я не знаю повної відповіді на це запитання:

- Я знаю, що тире часто ставиться (замість двокрапки) перед переліком по факту.
- Я знаю, що правила російської пунктуації, які не завжди збігаються з українськими, але часто прописані детальніше, це явно дозволяють ([Розенталь, § 72, п. 1](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189#ppp_1)).
- Деякі підручники [зазначають](http://pidruchniki.com/1494080740591/dokumentoznavstvo/punktuatsiya): «Іноді замість двокрапки після узагальнювального слова можна ставити тире.» Але при цьому, на жаль, додають: «У таких випадках однорідні члени мають характер побіжного зауваження…» — що не відповідає нашій ситуації.

Можливо, можна аргументувати просто [§ 121, п. 17](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil5.htm#par121p17) — інтонаційною паузою?

Comment: Хм… А Наталі правильно [пише](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/1377/4) про прикладки. Виходить, кожну з двокрапок (або навіть обидві відразу) можна за бажанням замінити на тире, тому що обидва випадки можна інтерпретувати як прикладки (чи я неправий, і прикладки можуть бути лише іменними?).

Answer (score 1):

А я б залишила першу двокрапку, а перед «консервами і яблуками» поставила б тире, бо тут це виглядає як прикладка: «з новими трофеями *(якими?)* — консервами і яблуками».

[Пункт 7 параграфу 121 правопису 2015](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil5.htm#par121p7) каже:

> Тире ставиться: <…>
>
> Для виділення **прикладок**, якщо вони стоять у кінці речення й перед ними можна, не змінюючи змісту, вставити «а саме»:
>
> > У своїм невеличкім гурточку він *[Гуща]* завів новину — гуртову працю *(Коцюбинський)*.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! На жаль, цей допис не відповідає нашим критеріям якості. (1) він відображає лише персональну точку зору автора; (2) він не надає науково-обґрунтованого пояснення. Будь ласка, перегляньте сусідню відповідь (вона — якісна), а також відповіді до інших запитань. Також може бути корисним  [tour]. Ви завжди можете відредагувати [edit] свою відповідь і поправити ці недоліки.